# How to add result of if condition as a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data:

```
    GUID  Standard_Grades
     123  3,4
     258  PK, K,1
     228  10,11,12
     555  5,6,7
```

I do the following,

```
  Grade_list = ["PK","K","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
  for i in range(0,len(df)):
      Standard_list = df.iloc[i]['Standard Grades']
      Standard_list = list(Standard_list.split(" "))
      Standard_list = Standard_list[0].split(",")
      my_list = f(Grade_list,Standard_list) #Function f is defined below
      df["New_col"] = my_list
```

where the function f is defined as

```
def f(Grade_list,Standard_list):

    if (Standard_list[0] == 'PK' and Standard_list[-1] != '12'):
       Standard_list  = Standard_list +[Grade_list[Grade_list.index(Standard_list[-1]) + 1]]
    elif (Standard_list[0] != 'PK' and Standard_list[-1] == '12'):
         Standard_list = [Grade_list[Grade_list.index(Standard_list[0]) + -1]] + Standard_list
    elif (Standard_list[0] == 'PK' and Standard_list[-1] == '12'): 
         Standard_list = Standard_list
    else:  
         Standard_list = [Grade_list[Grade_list.index(Standard_list[0]) - 1]] + Standard_list + [Grade_list[Grade_list.index(Standard_list[-1]) + 1]]
```

I want to add the "my_list" in a new column for every Standard_Grades in the data.

The expected output is,

```
    GUID  Standard_Grades  New_col
     123  3,4               ["2","3","4","5"]
     258  PK, K,1           ["PK","K","1","2"]
     228  10,11,12          ["9","10","11","12","13"]
     555  5,6,7             ["4","5","6","7","8"]
```

Comment: Hi selvapriya vel, welcome on SO. Do you mind to read [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please provide the info @rpanai requested. Among other points, you would need to describe, what `Grade_list` is and what the code `Grade_list[Grade_list.index(Standard_list[-1]) + 1]` is supposed to do (should it really only return one element?, are you sure, the last grade in `Standard_list` is contained in the `Grade_list`?, ...).

Comment: If you don't mind, please also correct your code above, so it at least can be executed. Function definitions in Python are done like `def f()` or `def f(arguments_separated_by_commas)` (in case they expect arguments). Just like I had it in my post. If you don't do that it will be hard to believe, you really tried with more effort to get to a solution yourself.